# Double click and run the Php script on mac

Tags: php, html, macos

I am sorry if this question was answered.

Why can't I run php code directly  without using terminal on mac.What I mean when you double click on html file it automatically opens in the browser but not in the case of php.If I try to double click on php it opens with some text-editor.

Any help would be helpful.

Comment: php requires a php-interpreter which are usually only availible on webservers. Take a look at XAMPP, you can host a local webserver and execute your php scripts on your local machine.

Comment: But mac comes with php installed.I can run the php file but I need to manually type in the file name[path name].

Comment: You should take a computer course first, learn what is executable and what not and learn about default application of files and then at last learn about PHP code how it is executed and what is reading/executing the code (Definitely not the browser).

Comment: @Houssni Dude of course it runs on server side.

Answer (score 53):

Try this (for mac),

1. Open `terminal`
2. `cd` to folder
3. Start php server - `php -S 127.0.0.1:8000`
4. Open browser and enter - `http://localhost:8000/file-name.php`

Comment: Thanks, this is the only solution that matters.

Answer (score 14):

I think you don't understand what PHP is ...

HTML is a markup-language, that can directly be understood by the browser. If the browser opens the file, it can do something with the content.

As PHP is a programming-language, you need a parser. This parser is your PHP executable. This program can understand PHP and does nothing more, than running the code and giving something as result. This result may be an  HTML webpage, an image or whatever.

Since you said, you're using a mac, here's a quick introduction on how to set up your personal webserver:

On Mac OSX, PHP and Apache (that's what I use in this example) is already installed and pre-configured. You can just start using it like this:

Go into your system preferences and verify that `Web Sharing` is enabled.

Open the Finder and go to `/Library/WebServer/Documents/localhost`. All files that are in there are processed by the local webserver (Apache and PHP, if you want to know that). Place your file in there and open your webserver and call `http://localhost/YourFile.php` and it will call the file `YourFile.php` and show you what the output of the script is.

**EDIT:**

If you are using PHP for scripts, like bash-scripts, see the answer @andreas-baumgart provided.

Comment: Dude I know Php is a server side,but I was new to mac so.By the way Web sharing is removed just need to enable using sudo apachectl start

Comment: @rak, but you wrote your question as someone, not knowing what a webserver is ... or that you need it to open your website in a browser.

Comment: I was using mac for the first time so I thought it should work when we double click it as server was on.

Answer (score 9):

To run PHP in MAC, one should start the built-in Apache Web server and also enable the PHP already installed.

This can be done with the following steps.

1. Go to `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` and change the permission to `sudo chmod 777 httpd.conf`
2. Then open the above file to uncomment the line `#LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so`
3. To start the apache built-in server, use the command `sudo apachectl start` in the terminal.

Now .php files can be created and run from the terminal using `php -f filename.php` and it can also be run on a browser using `http://localhost/filename.php`

Answer (score 6):

You cannot execute plain PHP scripts as they are no executable programs but source code. As such they contain just the receipt for an interpreter to create executable code. In order to run your PHP script you need to pass it to the PHP interpreter. In your scenario you can archive that by providing a [shebang](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang).

To run your script on double click try this:

1. Make the script executable using `chmod +x yourscript.php`
2. Prepending the according Shebang to the files content: `#!/usr/bin/env php`.
3. Select a PHP file in Finder, hit CMD-i and change "Open With" to "Terminal.app".

Answer (score 4):

Late response, but was looking into doing this for myself, this coming up as one of the results in my searching wanted to provide 2 solutions since I ultimately came to both on my own.

## Solution #1

The simple way is to go a round about way by writing a wrapper file to execute the script you're working on. Create a file with the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

include('name-of-php-script.php');

?>
```

Save it as *wrapper.command* The name wrapper isn't important, but the command extension tells Finder that this is a shell script to open up in Terminal. The file itself just executes whatever php script is in the include.

## Solution #2

The specific inquiry requires a bit of work.

First make sure that the 1st line of the php script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
```

This is where the preinstalled version of PHP is installed on Mac OS X. You can always verify by running this command in terminal:

```
whereis php
```

Once you've added the Shebang line to the php script you've readied it for automatic execution.

To make it double clickable executeable you have to do the following:
Right click on the PHP script and click **Get Info**. Click where it says **Open With**, click the default option to see all the available options. Select **Other...**

Switch where it says **Enable:** from *Recommended Applications* to *All Applications*, and click the checkbox for **Always Open With**. Choose Terminal as the application. Finally, you have to click the button that says **Change All...**

OS X will verify you want it to set Terminal as the default application to open .php files

This will make every php file open up in terminal by default, but unless they contain the #!/usr/bin/php line they won't actually run.

Answer (score 3):

## Try [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/)

MAMP 4 brings even more opportunities for web developers. We are now supporting MySQL 5.6 and Nginx is now fully integrated. Server starting times have been improved.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because .php files are not 'executable' per se, instead they are just text files with a PHP extension.

You need to run the php interpreter against the file to execute on it's contents.